# How to list all dates in a month from jquery datepicker?

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, date

I am using jquery ui plugin for date picker.

Now I need to read the year and month from user to create an array of all dates in that month in the format "`yyyy-mm-dd`". How can I get dates like this from datepicker?

Comment: Oh thats great.So whats your question.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, hope this is what you need

```
var indate = $("#checkedin").val();
var date1 = indate.split("-");
var month = date1[1];
var year = date1[0];
var month_days = [0,31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31]; //days in each month, complete the array
var result = [];

for (var i = 1; i < month_days[month]; i++) {
    var date = i
    if (i < 10) {
        date = "0"+i;
    }
    if (month < 10) {
    month = "0"+month;
    }
    result.push(year+"-"+month+"-"+date);
}
```

Comment: not exactly ,I want all the dates in a particular month of year 
and the result should contain valid dates only . fro example if i chose month 2013-feb the result array should contain all dates in that feb-2013,like 2013-02-01,2013-02-02,2013-02-03,  this list shold not contain a date for a non existing day (2013-02-30)

Comment: one can not give you exactly what you want, you have to modify the code yourself to attain your requirements

Comment: what did you try yourself so far?

Comment: above script includes the functionality to push only existing dates in the array

Comment: the requirement in my application is creating playlist for a month
that means the user is provided with an interface to chose a date(year and month)
then a button for create playlist.when pressing the button i am making an entry to database for all days in that month.....i want to avoid the non existing dates.now i am inserting all the 31 days...so there is entries for non existing dates in database

Comment: you should post your code, and let us know where are you failing

Comment: your code isgood ....i think i only have to check an extra condition for leap years...